# How to write scripts for trigger which will run function every month from 25 to end of the month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need create trigger in Google sheets which will run some function from 25 date to last date for every month. 
I've tried to write some code, but I am not sure that it is correct resolve my problem:

```js
function triggerDate() {
 for (i=25; i<32; i++){  
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("simpleTrig")
 .timeBased()
 .onMonthDay(i)
 .create();
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Your code is working with no problems for me, creating the 7 triggers as you wanted. Do you have a `simpleTrig` function inside the same script where you're running `triggerDate` function right?

Comment: No, it works good. But I wanna to have script for creating triggers with more extended functional :) kinda it was proposed by @Cooper. Unfortunately, some of  his scripts do not work at me, by unknown reason.

Comment: Please describe in your question what do you mean by `with more extended functional`?

Comment: I interested in next features: setting triggers from google sheets,  manually  and selectively delete triggers from sheets and combine different types of triggers in one such as timeBased and onOpen. All this I wanna to realize by html form in sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way.

```
function createMonthlyTriggers() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Triggers');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hdrToIdx={};
  var hdrToCol={};
  hA.forEach(function(hdr,i){hdrToIdx[hdr]=i;hdrToCol[hdr]=i+1});
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!isATrigger(vA[i][hdrToIdx['FunctionName']])) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger(vA[i][hdrToIdx['FunctionName']]).timeBased().onMonthDay(vA[i][hdrToIdx['Day']]).atHour(vA[i][hdrToIdx['Hour']]).create();  
    }
  });
}

function isATrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Using a spreadsheet like this:

[image]

And you could use a function like this to display and delete triggers:

```
function displayProjectTriggers() {
  var tA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;padding:2px;margin:2px;}</style><table><tr><th>Handler Function</th><th>Trigger Type</th><th>Unique ID</th><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.run.displayProjectTriggers();}).deleteTrigger(\'%s\');" /></td></tr>',tA[i].getHandlerFunction(),tA[i].getEventType(),tA[i].getUniqueId(),tA[i].getHandlerFunction());
  }
  html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Project Triggers');
}
```

Here's the deleteTrigger function:

```
function deleteTrigger(triggerName){
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    if (triggerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What must be format for cells in Triggers sheet, because I can not run scripts due to error: "The passed in argument must be greater than zero" in line:ScriptApp.newTrigger(vA[i][hdrToIdx['FunctionName']]).timeBased().onMonthDay(vA[i][hdrToIdx['Day']]).atHour(vA[i][hdrToIdx['Hour']]).create();

Comment: Are your header names exactly the same as mine  no extra spaces?

Comment: Yes, I've resolved this problem, Ive write days in column Day as string e.x.  '25 instead of 25. But I got one more problem, script create only one trigger for 1st row and nothing else

Comment: Botton Delete in displayProjectTriggers does not work.  'Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).deleteTrigger is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick'

Comment: I’ll take a look at it when I get to my computer I just did it last night on mine I thought it worked

Comment: It works okay in my code.  I use it a lot.  Perhaps you didn't  get the whole line copied as it is an  extremely long line.

Comment: It seems strange because Ive got whole code. May be if you have time you could look on my simple project. I commented one line **<//if(!isATrigger(vA[i][hdrToIdx['FunctionName']])) {>** it was necessary for creating all triggers. If I let be as it is script will create only one first triger:). link for sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FsUSj9Xkk3SQs8B9T6vZ9hdS6fz_b0AgI80J3Vwc29U/edit#gid=1063396074 and link for project: https://script.google.com/d/1O1i9ofgFjk5hbraqBkFuX3MCotv41pVaF2-4NtQBv_5i_0nEqBNQkQDS/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to create a `deleteTrigger` function in your code.gs in which you should add the code to delete the trigger.

Comment: Oh that’s right I have the delete trigger function in another page on my code, I’ll copy it for you. Sorry about that.

Comment: Superb, Thanks @Cooper and @'Andres Duarte'
for help! I am a beginner in this topic and some easy errors becoming for me as really problems, but I am full of beans to learn JavaScript :)